# How to create a stripeRole for mode 'payment' in Stripe for Firebase?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

I spent few days reading the doc and watching tutos on how to use Stripe in Firebase to introduce premium content on my website. Except for one thing I don't want to make create a subscription.

I want to make a one-time payment so customers can enjoy a lifetime service.
Using subscriptions with `firestore-stripe-payments` extension it's pretty straightforward. When the customer buys something and gets redirected back to the app, the `user` custom claims object contains the `stripeRole` value equals to whatever you defined in the `firebaseRole` metadata on a given product.

But that doesn't seem to be an option for one-time payment, I've tried different values and settings but there is nothing in the custom claims object which can help determine if a user purchased the service or not.

Either I am not doing things correctly or there are actually no way to connect both ends without me having to implement a custom function to forward an indicator to the front.

I thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/master/firestore-stripe-payments/functions/src/index.ts), it looks like `role` is only considered in the subscription context, so what you're describing seems to be an unsupported use case.

You'd need to customize the code to build this functionality.

Comment: I need to read that source code more thoroughly, thanks. And I need to try passing metadata during the checkout session creation phase to see if that can help to forward values up to the end-user. It's unfortunate that they haven't implemented that by default, isn't one-time payment a typical case for unlocking services in an application? (that's just like a subscription but without an expiration date in the end...).